# Video goes under nav-bar when scrolled down?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website with a nav-bar and a video however when I scroll down the nav-bar stays in its position and the content goes under it.I thought that this might be because of `Z-index`  however I have tried and the problem still occurs.How do I get the ***whole*** web-content to scroll down without overlapping?

## HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>About us</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="About.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="banner animated"><img class="hero-image" src="https://picsum.photos/1080/200/?random"></div>
    <div class="nav-bar"> <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div style="padding-top:350px;" align="center" >
  <video width="1000" controls style="z-index: -2;">
  <source src="../../../Documents/Unnamed Site 2/Boku no Hero Academia AMV - Till I Collapse.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
    </div>
<p> dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text

 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text

  dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text

 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text

  dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text

 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text

  dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text dummy text

 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text
 dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text

  dummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy textdummy text </p>
</body>

</html>
```

## CSS

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,500,900';
    body {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    nav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
    }

    .banner {
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    }

    nav ul#menu {
      padding-left: 0;
      display: flex;
    }

    nav ul li {
      flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .nav-bar {
      /* Rectangle 1: */
      background: #FFFFFF;
      box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11), 0px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    /*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      position: absolute;
    }
    /*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

    li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    /*Style for menu links*/

    li a {
      display: block;
      min-width: 140px;
      height: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #fff;
      background: #2f3036;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    /*Hover state for top level links*/

    li:hover a {
      background: #19c589;
    }
    /*Style for dropdown links*/

    li:hover ul a {
      background: #f3f3f3;
      color: #2f3036;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
    }
    /*Hover state for dropdown links*/

    li:hover ul a:hover {
      background: #19c589;
      color: #fff;
    }
    /*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

    li ul {
      display: none;
    }
    /*Make dropdown links vertical*/

    li ul li {
      display: block;
      float: none;
    }
    /*Prevent text wrapping*/

    li ul li a {
      width: auto;
      min-width: 100px;
    }
    /*Display the dropdown on hover*/

    ul li a:hover+.hidden,
    .hidden:hover {
      display: block;
    }
    /*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

    .show-menu {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      background: #19c589;
      text-align: center;
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      display: none;
    }
    /*Hide checkbox*/

    input[type=checkbox] {
      display: none;
    }
    /*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

    input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
      display: block;
    }
    /*Responsive Styles*/

    @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
      /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
      nav ul#menu {
        position: static;
        display: none;
      }
      /*Create vertical spacing*/
      li {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
      }
      /*Make all menu links full width*/
      ul li,
      li a {
        width: 100%;
      }
      /*Display 'show menu' link*/
      .show-menu {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    .hero-image {
      /* The image used */
      /* Set a specific height */
      height: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
      vertical-align: top;
    }

    #menu {
      margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your navbar has a `position: fixed` property, which makes the navbar fixed in its position at all times, even when scrolling. Removing that property will probably fix your problem.

Comment: I changed it to position:relative and it started working